# Android: How to set password property in an edit text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to create a login form with 'username' 'password' fields and two buttons 'login' and 'cancel' in my android application.

I am using an alert dialog with edittext inside that.

This is the code I used to create password edittext..

```
     final EditText Password = new EditText(this);
     Password.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     Password.setHint("Password");
     Password.setWidth(200);

     Password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
     login_alert.addView(Password);
```

My issue is that, plain text is shown instead of 'dots' when i open a softkeypad to edit the password. (It is shown as dots when not in softkeypad mode)

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Your member naming style will get you in trouble. What if `Password` is a real existing class, god beware one with static methods.

Comment: I tried renaming.. still no luck

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
Password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

This one works for me.
But you have to look at Octavian Damiean's comment, he's right.

Comment: Thanks a lot ernazm.. This one works fine. I have on more qn.. My "Password.setHint("Password");" seems not working now. Any idea?

Comment: Strange. Just tried to combine `setHint` with `setInputType` and it worked for me just fine. That's my code: `EditText Password = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1));
        Password.setHint("Password");
        Password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22255310/426227) is some explanation why you need both `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` and `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`.

Comment: in case of Kotlin you should write             "password.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD"

Answer (score 28):

*This is deprecated*

In xml of EditText iclude this attribute: **android:password="true"**

**Edit**

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Comment: android:password="true" is deprecated

Answer (score 13):

Here's a new way of putting dots in password

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="@string/pwprompt" /
```

**add** android:inputType = "textPassword"

Comment: It seems to be the recommended way for xml declaration. http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()` instead of `new PasswordTransformationMethod()`.

Answer (score 4):

The only way that worked for me using code (not XML) is this one:

```
etPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
etPassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 3):

See this link 
**[text view android:password](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3apassword)**

This applies for `EditText` as well, as it is a known direct subclass of `TextView`.

Comment: @PareshMayani, I'm sorry, my friend, but EditText is a subclass of TextView. Now, please stop "-1"-ing everything you are not aware of or you think is wrong

Comment: @PareshMayani and what's with the comment? You might as well improved my answer if you felt it wasn't straightforward

Answer (score 3):

I found when doing this that in order to set the gravity to center, and still have your password hint show when `using inputType`, the `android:gravity="Center"` must be at the end of your XML line.

```
<EditText android:textColor="#000000" android:id="@+id/editText2" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:hint="Password" 
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/imageButton1" 
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/imageButton1" 
    android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/editText1" 
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" 
    android:textColorHint="#999999" 
    android:textSize="16dp" 
    android:gravity="center">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 3):

To set password enabled in EditText, We will have to set an "inputType" attribute in xml file.If we are using only EditText then we will have set input type in EditText as given in below code.

```
                    <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_Edit"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:hint="password"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/next"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Password enable attribute is

```
 android:inputType="textPassword"
```

But if we are implementing Password EditText with Material Design (With Design support library) then we will have write code as given bellow.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/txtInput_currentPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_Edit"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_currentpassword"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/next"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

@Note: - In Android SDK 24 and above, "passwordToggleEnabled" is by default true. So if we have the customs handling of show/hide feature in the password EditText then we will have to set it false in code as given above in .

```
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
```

To add above line, we will have to add below line in root layout.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 1):

My search for a similar solution for Visual Studio 2015/Xamarin lead me to this thread.  While setting the `EditText.InputType` to  `Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword` properly hid the password during user entry, it did not 'hide' the password if it was visible before the EditText Layout was rendered (before the user submitted their password entry).  In order to hide a visible password after the user submits their password and the EditText Layout is rendered, I used `EditText.TransformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.Instance` as suggested by LuxuryMode.