# Password InputField Censored (****) - Logging and Registration

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am planning to do logging and registration. But I have a problem. I can't make the password InputField became like ***** (censored).

And maybe it wouldn't affect your answers but my game will be on the android platform.

[image: Here is the sample image]

Thank you.

Comment: How you have declared password field? And does show text in password enabled on phone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094962/android-how-to-set-password-property-in-an-edit-text

Comment: I use UI. I havent seen password field setting for UI. And show text is enabled. but I dont wanna hide text. I just want to add * when he wrote one character. E.g. when the player click on 'h' it should write '', than 'i' to ''. But not when he done writing like 'hi' to '**'

Answer (score 25):

now you have a property in unity than you can change directly change . you select content type in Input field text and your value is change[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `EditText` and set its `inputType="textPassword`

Herr is also an example to do so:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-password-field-example/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
public string thePassword = "12345";
void OnGUI()
{
    passwordToEdit = GUI.PasswordField(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 20), 
                                       passwordToEdit, "*"[0], 25);
}
```

#### PasswordField Parameter List

1. Where you would like the box.
2. Your password to mask.
3. The character to mask the password characters with.
4. *(Optional)* Max masking length.
5. *(Optional)* The textfield style.

[Source: Unity Scripting API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.PasswordField.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about using InputField of the new UI ? 
You can set the content to Password:

Doc:

http://docs.unity3d.com/es/current/Manual/script-InputField.html