# I am using editText for password field in android. How to show the password visible for few seconds and then mask it with asterisk symbol?

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords

The output should look like following image:

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1F8fEghZUUQ/WcygBf8ZANI/AAAAAAAAAe0/eOH24v9yreAvlrtF4QmRAQtF4yfBk3n9QCK8BGAs/s512/2017-09-28.jpg]

Comment: show what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is not a code writing service, you have to show what you have tried, explain why it does not work and provide simple way of reproducing the problem. Please consult "How to ask a good question" manual and update your question by adding relevant information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to set password property in an edit text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094962/android-how-to-set-password-property-in-an-edit-text)

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more simple way   use **[TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html)**

compile design library to your dependecies

```
compile "com.android.support:design:26.0.+"
```

> **[TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html)**
>   Layout which wraps an EditText (or descendant) to show a floating label when the hint is hidden due to the user inputting text.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter EMail Address"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```